# Square Free Word in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm stuck on creating a program to solve a question for a class. I have a main method and a secondary testing method that are working in conjunction to solve this problem, however I can't get the solution to work when there's a change.
The problem is making sure a word is square free, here's an excerpt from the problem:

> For this part, implement a method called isSquareFree that takes as input (a reference to ) an array of characters. You may assume that the elements of the array are all lower case letters. (In other words, you do not need to worry about a question like: "is Z the same letter as z?") Your method should test if the given input array of characters is square-free. If it is, the method should print a message stating that, otherwise it should print a message stating that the world is not square-free, where the square subword starts and what that subword is. For example, if the given array contained the word zatabracabrac the method should print: The word, zatabracabrac, is not square free, since it has subword, abrac twice starting at position 4 of the word.

Below is the current code I have, it works in the case that there is a repeating character directly next to each other, but I'm unsure of how to continue to check if there is multiple repeating characters (abab for example) nor am I sure how to print out the repeating subword.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // part (a) of the main

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("***************************");
    System.out.println("        Part (a)");
    System.out.println("***************************");

    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a word and then press enter:");
        String str=keyboard.next();
        char[] word = str.toCharArray();

        isSquareFree(word);
        System.out.println("Do you want to test another word? Press y for yes, or another key for no");

    }while(keyboard.next().charAt(0)=='y');


}

public static void isSquareFree(char[] word){
    int sqf = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<word.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<word.length-1;j++){
            if (word[j] == word[j+1]){
                sqf = 1;
                j = word.length;
            }
            else{
                sqf = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sqf == 1){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Not Square Free");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Square Free");
    }
}}
```

I'd also like to add that I'm not allowed to use the arrays class for this question, nor am I allowed to use strings and I cannot change the main method, not can I change the input for my other method.

Comment: "For example, if the given array contained the word zatabracabrac the method should print:" - print what? Can you explain what "square free" means?

Comment: "The word, zatabracabrac, is not square free, since it has subword, abrac twice starting at position 4 of the word."

That was my mistake, I forgot that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To see if a sequence of characters repeats, for a given sequence length (say, *n*), you would replace your `if` with a loop that compares `word[j+x]` with `word[j+n+x]` for each value of `x` between 0 and *n*; and only consider them the same if all *n* match.  Thus, you'd need to loop over these *n* values for `x`; if you need to consider different values of *n*, then you'd need yet another loop to go through those.

   It isn't clear from your code what you are using `i` for, but if it is the length of the repeating part (what I've called *n*), then you'd only need to consider values up to half the length of `word` (or else there isn't room to repeat it).
2. To print out a sub word, you could print out each individual letter in order (using `print` instead of `println`)

Comment: I'm still really lost with what you're trying to say. I'll keep working at it and comment again if I make any progress. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Based on what you told me I got it to work! Thank you so much!